# Someone who has passed lots of difficulties in their lives

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, register

Please suppose someone who has had lots of difficulties in his life and has passed many problems so far. Someone who had been without money, food and even a home to live in for a long time and as the saying goes a destitute one at the real meaning of the word. He has gained lots f success because of hardworking during the last several years and he is over the hump at the time being and at the time he is talking about his past to someone who is going to know about his past and he is telling to that individual about his hard times in the past. Which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to you:

> - I had a lot of hard times in my life.
> - I have gone through a lot of hard times in my life.
> - I have had a lot of difficulties in my life.
> - I have suffered a lot of hardships in my life.

Please let me know if they all sound weird to you and then tell me what shall I use instead in normal English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They **have been through** hard times.
>
> They **are going through** hard times.

are common ways of saying it.

Most likely, if the phrase has "suffered" and "hardships" in it, it will also have "many", not "a lot of":

> She has suffered many hardships.

Comment: Thank you very much TRomano, but now knowing the most common ways to say it, could you please tell me if  my sentences are idiomatic. Are they natural too @TRomano? Especially # 2.

Comment: They are all idiomatic except perhaps with the last one, where to my ear there is a slight register clash.  #2 strikes my ear as idiomatic but a little awkward with "a lot of".

Comment: Then please let me know changing it in this way: "I have gone through many hard times in my life" it would sound awkward an d unnatural again @TRomano? And Also "I had many hard times in my life". And perhaps "I have had many difficulties in my life"

Comment: **hard times** most often is used in terse, laconic, even understated utterances, and is rarely if ever modified with "a lot of" or "many". You might hear **He has gone through some very hard times**. Ngram would seem to corroborate this: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gone+through+hard+times%2Cgone+through+many+hard+times&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgone%20through%20hard%20times%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Great job. And what about #3 @TRomano?

Comment: #3,  **difficulties** is OK with "a lot of" or "many". But I still prefer **many**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overcome+many+difficulties%2Covercome+a+lot+of+difficulties&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Covercome%20many%20difficulties%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Covercome%20a%20lot%20of%20difficulties%3B%2Cc0  But a lot of people would say "a lot of".